In chrome, The pin is placed somewhere other than where click on leaflet
I have a leaflet map in an html page (I put my code below). When I open it in chrome browser and click on the map, it puts the pin somewhere other than where I clicked. But it works fine in FF browser.
var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 51.66509977740657, lat: 32.622378058018654}, 16);                           
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 19}).addTo(map);
L.control.scale({imperial: true, metric: true}).addTo(map);

map.on('click',function(e) {
    lat = Number(e.latlng.lat.toFixed(6));
    lon = Number(e.latlng.lng.toFixed(6));

    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You Clicked Lat: " + lat+" & Lon: "+lon)
        .openOn(map);

    if (theMarker != undefined) {
        map.removeLayer(theMarker);
};

theMarker = L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map);

Any idea?
I googled a lot this problem but couldn't find a solution.

I found the problem. This was the interference with my bootstrap template, which was used for the side bar and in which the display with less than 1200px width, contents changed to 85% and this would make the pin being located elsewhere.

You are missing closing bracelet for your if statement / onClick function:
var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 51.66509977740657, lat: 32.622378058018654}, 16);                           
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 19}).addTo(map);
L.control.scale({imperial: true, metric: true}).addTo(map);

map.on('click',function(e) {
    lat = Number(e.latlng.lat.toFixed(6));
    lon = Number(e.latlng.lng.toFixed(6));

    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You Clicked Lat: " + lat+" & Lon: "+lon)
        .openOn(map);

    if (theMarker != undefined) {
        map.removeLayer(theMarker);
    } // this was missing
};

theMarker = L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map);


Thank you for your reply. I fixed it but it still doesn't work
